# Is it right to use Jquery Selectors in javascript variable and how to get cities and districts with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am using jQuery for making management panels. Some of them are simple and some of them are more interactive. I am getting someone's name from an input type text that has id name. Which is the right way to do this?

```
1 - ) $("#name").val();

2 - ) let name = $("#name");
      console.log(name.val());
```

My another question is
if you put all city list in select . These cities have also districts related to them and they are in also select. JQuery ajax works async and preferred way is also using async. If I prepare a create page for example, for adding company , I need to get first cities then districts like this

```js
function getDistricts(cityId) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Administrator/General/GetDistricts?cityId=" + cityId,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    success: function (response) {
      if (response.success === true) {
        companyDistrict.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          companyDistrict.append('<option value="' + response.data[i].id + '">' + response.data[i].name + '</option>');
        }
      }
      else {
        fireAlert(response.success, response.message);
      }
    },
    error: function (error) {
      fireAlert(false, error.statusText);
    }
  });
}
function getGetCities() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Administrator/General/GetCities",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    success: function (response) {
      if (response.success === true) {
        companyCity.append('<option value="' + '0' + '">' + 'İl seçiniz.' + '</option>');
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          companyCity.append('<option value="' + response.data[i].id + '">' + response.data[i].name + '</option>');
        }
      }
      else {
        fireAlert(response.success, response.message);
      }
    },
    error: function (error) {
      fireAlert(false, error.statusText);
    }
  });
}
```

and on update page for company. My code is like that

```js
function getGetCities(cityId,districtId) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Administrator/General/GetCities",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    success: function (response) {
      if (response.success === true) {
        companyCity.append('<option value="' + '0' + '">' + 'İl seçiniz.' + '</option>');
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          companyCity.append('<option value="' + response.data[i].id + '">' + response.data[i].name + '</option>');
        }
        companyCity.val(cityId);
        getDistricts(cityId, districtId);
      }
      else {
        fireAlert(response.success, response.message);
      }
    },
    error: function (error) {
      fireAlert(false, error.statusText);
    }
  });
}
function getDistricts(cityId, districtId) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Administrator/General/GetDistricts?cityId=" + cityId,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    success: function (response) {
      if (response.success === true) {
        companyDistrict.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          companyDistrict.append('<option value="' + response.data[i].id + '">' + response.data[i].name + '</option>');
        }
        companyDistrict.val(districtId);
      }
      else {
        fireAlert(response.success, response.message);
      }
    },
    error: function (error) {
      fireAlert(false, error.statusText);
    }
  });
}
```

I am just wondering that if I use the right way. Is this way right and how can i use jquery and javascript with asp.net core effectively ?

Comment: Does your code work? If `yes` then it's the "right way."

Comment: The way to get the input name is correct.  In es6, let declares local variables, The second idea is also correct. In addition, you can use jQuery's cascading list plugin, such as: https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Dynamic-jQuery-Cascading-Dropdown-Lists-Plugin.html